MAUI IOS Background fetch Task Not Trigger
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    RegisterForRemoteNotifications(application);
    BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Register("com.example.AppName.refresh", null,  task => {
         HandleAppRefreshTask(task as BGAppRefreshTask);
    });
    
    application.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);
    ScheduleAppRefresh();
    
    return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
}
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
{
    ScheduleAppRefresh();
    base.DidEnterBackground(application);
}
private void RegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application)
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
        UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
        (isSuccess, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                // no op, not going to do anything about this for now
            }
        });

    application.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}

void HandleAppRefreshTask(BGAppRefreshTask task)
{
    
    ScheduleAppRefresh(); // Reschedule the next refresh task

    var queue = new NSOperationQueue();
    queue.AddOperation(() =>
    {
        var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent
        {
            Title = "Test",
            Body = "Random Number58",
            Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default
        };

        // Trigger to repeat every 5 minutes
        var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(5, false);

        var requestID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Generate unique identifier

        // Create a notification request
        var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);

        // Schedule the notification
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
        {
            if (err != null)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine($"Error scheduling notification: {err.LocalizedDescription}");
            }

        });
        // Perform the app refresh
        task.SetTaskCompleted(true);
    });

    task.ExpirationHandler = () =>
    {
        queue.CancelAllOperations();
        task.SetTaskCompleted(false);
    };
}

public static void ScheduleAppRefresh()
{
    var request = new BGAppRefreshTaskRequest("com.example.AppName.refresh")
    {
        EarliestBeginDate = NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(30) 
    };

    NSError error;
    if (!BGTaskScheduler.Shared.Submit(request, out error))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Could not schedule app refresh: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
    }
}

}
---------Info.plist------
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fetch</string>        
  </array>
   <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
   <array>
 <string>com.example.AppName.refresh</string>
</array>

I have implemented Code to send notification every 30 seconds even the app in closed state also But HandleAppRefreshTask(BGAppRefreshTask task) not triggerd But its not trigger. Any mistake i have done Please suggest

You can't expect a background task to run every 30 seconds. iOS will schedule it for a few times a day at most. There is a process for triggger your task during development.

After publish this will work?

Is there any other way to fetch data even the app is not running in foreground or background. like WhatsApp will receive notification even app is not running in foreground or background

Push notifications can deliver a notification to the user, but you can't deliver data to the app itself if it isn't running.
